# How can I get a Schengen visa to visit Germany?

Tags: applications, schengen-visas

I need a Schengen visa to travel to to visit a friend there. I am a foreign national who lives in South Africa with a life partner. I have my own registered/permitted business, which is about a year old.

I asked a travel agent to help me; he is asking for about $1100 to process a visa for me. That is too expensive, considering that I woud still need money to spend afterwards.

I thought about doing all the process myself but I have never been outside Africa.  How do I apply for a visa to visit Germany and stay there for a month or two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When considering a visa application, it's always best to start with the local diplomatic mission of the country you wish to visit.  Fortunately, the German mission to South Africa has a web page at https://southafrica.diplo.de/sa-en.

At the bottom of the home page is a [Visa](https://southafrica.diplo.de/sa-en/sa-consular/sa-visa1) link, which takes you to a page with two links on it; which link is correct for you depends on whether you plan to apply in Durban.

That should be enough to get you started.  Before you submit your application, you may want to read questions from people whose visa applications have been refused.  This will help you understand the kinds of things that visa officers consider when evaluating a visa application.  If you have questions that haven't already been asked on this site, you can post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to describe the premise and itinerary of your visit. It might be difficult to believe for the visa officials that the owner of a year-old business is going to take two months off for tourism.

In the application you will have to explain your economic circumstances and your reasons why you would return home (and not overstay).

- You have to show that you earn enough money to afford tourism. Two months in Germany can cost several thousand €, and the flight adds to that.
- You have to show a regular income and ties to the local economy.

Comment: Thank you @O.M Maybe i will just make it 3 week then, i have a good financial back up